# pgfplots with global enlargelimits

Tags: pgfplots

I want the same `enlargelimits` setting in all my pgfplots, to separate the arrow heads from the tickmarks. Therefore I want to add it to `\pgfplotsset` in the preable. Where do I have to put it?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17,
  % enlargelimits={value=0.1,upper}, %%% does not work
  every axis/.style={
    % enlargelimits={value=0.1,upper}, %%% does not work
    axis line style={-stealth},
    axis lines={center},
    scaled ticks=base 10:3,
    every x tick scale label/.style={
      at=(current axis.right of origin),
      right,
    },
    every y tick scale label/.style={
      at=(current axis.north west),
      above,
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits={value=0.1,upper}, %%% works just fine
    xtick scale label code/.code={$x \cdot 10^{#1}$},
    ytick scale label code/.code={$y \cdot 10^{#1}$},
    ]
    \addplot table {
      1e-3 1e-3
      3e-3 3e-3
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, after small changes of options order (see MWE below) and use recent `pgfplots` (v 1.18) it works for me:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.18,
axis line style = {-stealth},
     axis lines = {center},
  enlargelimits = {value=0.1,upper}, % <---now it works
            }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xtick scale label code/.code={$x \cdot 10^{#1}$},
    ytick scale label code/.code={$y \cdot 10^{#1}$},
    ]
    \addplot table {
      1e-3 1e-3
      3e-3 3e-3
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surprise, surprise! Thanks for your instant reply.